# Any way to crop the sides of any image with percentages without using libraries in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing

I want to make a function where the function trims a percentage of the image on all sides.

I want to write a function where the parameters are as follows: the image of which I want to crop the sides; how much of the image I want to crop on all of the sides (4 different percentages). I tried writing this, however this didn't work:

```
def cropImage2 (image, perL, perR, perB, perO):
widthL = image.shape[0] / 2
widthR = image.shape[0] / 2
heightAbove = image.shape[1] / 2
heightBelow = image.shape[1] / 2

linksBr = int(widthL * perL)
rechtsBr = int(widthR * perR)
bovenHg = int(heightAbove * perB)
onderHg = int(heightBelow * perO)

cropX = linksBr + rechtsBr
cropY = bovenHg + onderHg

arrayNieuweImage = np.zeros([cropX, cropY,3])

for i in range(1, cropX):
    for j in range(1, cropY):
        arrayNieuweImage[i, j] = image[i, j]

return arrayNieuweImage
```

What I want it to do: for example if I write cropImage2(image, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5), It should remove 30% of the leftside, 20% of the rightside, 40% on  the side above the middle line and 50% below the middle line

Any changes you would make to make this work? Thanks in advance

(I know it would be easier using libraries like openCV or PIL, but I want to do it without libraries)

Comment: You can just use Numpy slicing, so `arrayNieuweImage = image[bovenHg:onderHg, linksBr:rechtsBr]` or similar.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried doing that, but I got an error message:                                                      zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity

Comment: Ok, please show dimensions of original image and the values of boven, onder, links and rechts.

Comment: Dimensions original image: (512, 512, 3) /// the values of bovenHg, onderHg, linksBr and rechtsBr all change as a result of changing of the variables perL, perR, perB and per O

Comment: If you want to remove 10% off the top, 20% off the bottom, 30% off the left and 40% off the right, you need `new=old[51:410, 153:307]`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but can you tell me how you got those numbers, if I can understand how you got those numbers I could try and make it work in general

Comment: The new image will start 10% of the way from top to bottom, therefore 51 pixels from the top and will end 80% of the distance from top to bottom, therefore 410 pixels down from the top. The new image will start 30% in from the left, so 153 pixels in from the the left, and the new image will end  60% of the way from the left to the right, so 307 pixels from the left edge.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir